# Logging the progress of a servlet using a FileWriter

Tags: java, servlets, logging

I am trying to create a text file in which I will log the actions taken by the servlet, because it is running remotely and this is my best chance to debug it.

In its constructor, I do

```
logFile = new FileWriter("/absolutePath/WEB-INF/classes/a.txt");
fout = new BufferedWriter(logFile);
fout.write("Server is up and awaiting connections on port: " + PORT+"\n");
```

However, the file never gets created. Am I using the wrong path? Why am I not seeing anything? Any other simple suggestions of debugging the servlet? Please help me out, I can't even start debugging this.

Comment: I don't think you can create/update file under WEB-INF folder. I would suggest move your log file to outside project.

Comment: I think that create a file in WEB-INF folder is not a problem in his case, but when the application will be redeployed the log you be losed.  Maybe your path is wrong. Try to use an absolute (and simple) path to see what happens. Other thing. close your writer after using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use logging framework, for example log4j for logging purpose

Comment: And where will I see the logged statements? In the file? In console? On the web site?

Comment: File output would work, but why to take care of it by hand if we have already very good library for it

Comment: You say it runs remotely. Is this on your network? Has remote debug session been tried?

Comment: Right, but where will those log statements appear? If in file, what will be its name? I am running tomcat 5.

Comment: You can configure to log it anywhere you wish

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the error log on your server.  It might have a clue about why the write is failing.
2. If nothing helpful is there, try changing the logging level and restarting the server.
3. Also, look into java.util.logging.  You should be able to use `Logger.getLogger("custom-logger");` (the convention is to use the class name: `this.class.getName()`)

Source: I've been there on this one.

Comment: And  if I use log4j, where can I see the logged statements? By the way, where can I expect to find the logs of my server?

Comment: It's also possible that your permissions are preventing you from creating the file or that your absolute path is wrong.

Comment: It depends on what server you are running.

Comment: tomcat shared server for a school project

Comment: log4j works fine, too.  You will have to write a custom file handler to write to a specific file either way, which may overcomplicate things.  Sorry, I overlooked that part of your question: that you wanted to write to a specific file.

Comment: What version of tomcat are you using? (that actually matters, too)

Comment: It doesn't matter, I would write anywhere as long as it is simple and helps me debug this thing. So, what's the easiest thing I can do to print stuff from the servlet so that I know what it's doing and where it gets stuck?

Comment: Unfortunately, J2EE containers often change their layout between versions.

Comment: Hm, Ok, so is there not a simple way for me to print something anywhere to get at least some idea what the server is doing?

Comment: Honestly, you should be able to get away with a `System.out.println()` temporarily, but you need to know where your logs are.  If you're in unix, try `find (server_root) -iname "*log*"` I should add that any logging framework will write to the common log file, but you get nice things like custom file handlers and automatic formatting that you don't get from sysouts.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 5.0. And even if I do System.out, where will that statement get printed? I am running it on a remote server. And no, I didn't find any log files :(

Comment: From your proposed log message and that fact that you don't have any logs in your server, it sounds like you're not even sure if the server has started.  If that's the case, tomcat's logs aren't going to help you, because they aren't being generated.  Also, check the permissions on the folders in your server.  It's possible that your permissions are preventing the log files from being created.

Comment: Finally, try looking in catalina.out. http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=408202

Comment: Well, how can I check if it has started? The tomcat manager page says running, and when a client tries to connect, it gets a response that looks like xml description of the page I get when I click on the conext link, so I assume it is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of remote debugging ? Please debug it using [Remote Debugging](http://ihategeek.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/remote-debugging-with-eclipse-and-tomcat/) and you will understand the error if any. Also try using System.getProperty("user.dir") which will give you current directory in which program is running.

Also please see [Java: writing to a file, where is the output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515745/java-writing-to-a-file-where-is-the-output-file)

Comment: No, I had no idea about remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can try such a code as below. This log file is created  using log4j

```
public class Logger
{

protected static FileHandler m_FileHandler;

protected static Logger m_logger = null;

public static void startAppLog()
{
    try {
        m_FileHandler = new FileHandler("D:\\test" + "\\" + "LogFile.log", true);
        final LogManager logMngr = LogManager.getLogManager();
        m_logger = Logger.getLogger(NmsLogger.class.getName());
        }
     catch (final SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this kind of code? In the servlet class? And where will the file appear?

Comment: Create this file in a new class as named in the servlet. And the log file will be created in the location "D:\\test\\LogFile.log"